What adhesive properties does chewing gum have under conditions found in space?
Chewing gum, used as an adhesive, is a plot device employed to rescue intrepid heroes. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2694/where-did-they-get-all-of-the-gum-from
It is only a matter of time before gum will be be employed to plug a small hull breach or repair micro meteor damage to an antenna in space fiction.
How believable would this space fiction plot device be? What adhesive properties does chewing gum have under conditions found in space?
Adhesives use in space need to withstand a large range of temperature. Low temperature (to -115F) is a particular challenge. Approved adhesives also need to meet strict standards of outgassing and radiation resistance. https://www.masterbond.com/techtips/adhesives-space-applications
Chewing gum works as an adhesive due to Vand der Waals forces, as employed by “super glues”

Van der Waals forces… help bring the surfaces closer together,
facilitating bonding. These forces are responsible for the initial
contact and adhesion between … super glue and the surface.

https://threebondindia.com/science-behind-super-glue/#:~:text=Van%20der%20Waals%20forces%2C%20which,super%20glue%20and%20the%20surface
Chewing gum’s high pliability allows it to flow into microscopic crevices, increasing contact area. https://www.sciencefocus.com/science/what-makes-chewing-gum-bond-so-well . Vacuum desiccation and low temperatures increase bond strength so, once applied, conditions in space could enhance adhesive performance. However, radiation exposure would be expected to degrade polymers and therefore weaken the gum matrix with time.
The adhesive properties of chewing gum are substantial, as demonstrated by this study https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/tdcpublication/57/1/57_1/_pdf  However, when gum is pulled off a surface, most of the energy goes into stretching the polymers, rather  than breaking the bonds between the surface and the gum. https://illumin.usc.edu/chewing-gum Presumably this is why frozen gum is easier to remove: reduced elasticity of the polymer transmits force to the gum/surface interface.

If you are asking "how believable is it that a small hole would be patched with chewing gum" I would say that it's unlikely, but reasonably plausible/believable:
Unlikely to be used
Unlike sci-fi would have you believe, a small hole in the hull is not a huge issue, keyword being small. The current ISS already has a known "leak rate", which, in 2011 was ~0.227 kg/day and has increased since (recently, it has been as high as 0.9 kg/day in the Zvezda module alone).
If we assume a daily leak rate of 1 kg atmosphere lost, some back-of-the-envelope calculations give us an effective hole diameter of maybe 0.5 mm in Zvezda (assuming that all the leaks are one round hole). While this is sub-optimal, clearly handling this is not an abandon-station level disaster.
Because a hole of this size is clearly not an emergency, astronauts would have enough time to leisurely go fetch the proper equipment to do the job, and would not need to rely on improvisational patch jobs using chewing gum which might make sealing the hole properly later more difficult due to residue or similar.
If the hole is big enough that an immediate solution is required and the astronaut can't go fetch proper equipment, the hole is likely so big that gum couldn't reasonably be used to stuff the hole. Specifically, some more back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest that a hole of around 8 cm in diameter would result in a station-wide pressure drop of about 30% within 5 minutes, assuming all the doors are open, and you aren't going to be patching an 8 cm hole with a bit of chewing gum. Instead, for round and uniform holes, the astronauts would be better off plugging them with their fingers or hands until someone can go fetch more appropriate equipment.
Plausible
The biggest issue that chewing gum has as an emergency hole-patching solution is not adhesion, but rather viscosity. The pressure differential itself will force the system towards a perfect seal, pulling the gum into the hole, however, if it is too fluid or the hole is too large, the gum may simply be sucked through the hole, unable to withstand the pressure differential.
The calculation of "maximum hole size that could be patched by gum" is a nontrivial physics puzzle, but my instinct combined with my experience scraping gum off of places it shouldn't be, suggests that small holes, under 4mm in diameter, could reasonably and effectively be plugged by the amount of gum an astronaut might hypothetically be chewing.
In terms of temperature resistance, gum would probably be fine for a while because most hull breaches where an astronaut could stick some freshly-chewed material would be inside, and thus have a temperature compatible with human life. On the "outside" of the emergency gum-seal, there would be vacuum, yes, but it's unlikely that there would directly be "open space" since layers upon layers of non-airtight micrometeorite protection, structural systems, and thermal management are outside of the pressure hull. It is therefore unlikely that it would be directly exposed to the sun, and since it's so small, it would basically always just have the same temperature as the hull of the hole it's plugging.

A big problem developing tile repair materials for the shuttle that could be deployed from  a "goo gun" was their tendency to develop bubbles and swell when exposed to vacuum. Since gum "cracking" or "snapping" is due to air bubbles in it, I suspect it may exhibit the same behavior.

@Dragongeek ... you make good points about the limited gap-spanning capabilities of chewing gum. But the OP title is about adhesive properties.

@Woody Yes, and my point is that adhesion really isn't important in this case due to the pressure differential. I don't see how good it sticks as being relevant.

Here's how they fix a skull-sized hole on the MCRN Donnager in the Expanse: (CW: blood, deadly Injury): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RbaKLXvlNWM They use plastic or strong cardboard with some glue.

When I was on console for the August 2018 ISS atmospheric leak, the progression was Alexander Gurst's finger covering the hole, then some Kapton Tape, then some Gray Tape (duct tape), then lots of arguing between NASA and ROSCOSMOS about a permanent solution. Since it was in the Soyuz, ROSCOSMOS got the final say. They declined using the US IVA Leak Kit and instead made a patch that looked suspiciously like medical gauze mixed with JB Weld.

@Doresoom I think the astronaut you mean is called Alexander Gerst. Nice story.

it could be used to seal a square patch of some cardboard or something first

@quarague Whoops, thanks for catching my typo!

I agree with Dragongeek that adhesive properties are largely irrelevant for fixing holes. If you apply gum on the inside, the pressure will keep it in place; if you apply gum on the outside, the pressure will blow it away in any case.
However, adhesion might matter if you try to e.g. fix an antenna with chewing gum.
A common recommendation to get chewing gum off clothes is to freeze them. If a -15°C household freezer makes it easier to remove, we can expect that below -80°C gum won't stick well.
Modern chewing gum base is most commonly polyisobutylene polymer.
For pure PIB polymer, we have this graph from Adhesive Failure and Deformation Behaviour of Polymers (A. Zosel, 1989):

The fracture energy hits 0 at -25°C. Below this temperature there is practically no adhesion of chewing gum base. In a chewed chewing gum, there is also water which will freeze and will provide some adhesion, but in that case it would be more effective to use spit.

How could it be used outside a spacecraft to begin with? You can't open your helmet, take the gum out and use it without dying.

@GdD You bring the broken antenna to airlock, put gum on it, bring it back out :)

If you've taken the time to detach and bring the antenna in you'll have the time to find something better. I'm not criticizing your answer or anything, you're showing how it's not practical and I agree.

A really fun plot device would be having a micro-meteoroid pierce your helmet face shield, and then you spit the chewing gum to plug the hole :)

I'll try and channel my Andy Weir.

Sorry this answer just gave me the mental image of mashing gum across a micro meteor hole from outside and it starts blowing a giant bubble.

DarthPseudonym - meanwhile I can't get rid of the mental image of astronauts sticking their used gum behind an equipment rack.  @Doresoom, although it seems unlikely, have you ever heard of anyone discovering used chewing gum stuck somewhere?
